# how to utilize multiple celery workers to perform the same single task in python with flask

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

im currently handling a project which involved with flask, celery and redis. What im trying to do here now is to allow celery to perform same task in a multiple workers.

the reason is because im now trying to predict a real-time data where every second of the incoming data is essential, and therefore i need to predict an output of the data. so, right now i used celery and redis in order to perform the flask prediction.

the problem im facing is that the data which was inserted into the database was as if it was inserted after every each task was done. so, inserting the predicted output into the database after one task at a time is going to make the whole statistic delayed. so is there a way that i can allow multiple celery workers to perform one same task?

for my project, i had separated into fe layouts which was shown below:

```
new test
|___ __init__.py
|___ all.py
|___ celery_utils.py
|___ factory.py
|___ task.py
|___ utils.py
|___ celery_worker.py
|___ run.py
```

**init**.py

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app_name = __name__):
    #local
    redis_uri = "redis://172.30.30.224:6379/6"
    #production
    #redis_uri = "redis://192.168.33.122:6379/6"
    return Celery(app_name, backend=redis_uri, broker=redis_uri)
celery = make_celery()
```

task.py

```
from liveapp import celery
from datetime import datetime
from celery import shared_task
import re
from numpy import array, concatenate
from .utils import series_to_supervised,model_retrain, model_repredict, model_predict
import pyodbc
import gc

@celery.task()
def process_data(data):
    *perform some data cleaning and prediction*
```

run.py

```
from liveapp import factory
import liveapp
from waitress import serve

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = factory.create_app(celery = liveapp.celery)
    serve(app, host='127.0.0.1',port=50000)
```

celery_worker.py

```
from liveapp import celery
from liveapp.factory import create_app
from liveapp.celery_utils import init_celery
app = create_app()
init_celery(celery, app)
```

celery_utils.py

```
def init_celery(celery,app):
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)     
    celery.Task = ContextTask
```

factory.py

```
from flask import Flask
import os
from .celery_utils import init_celery

PKG_NAME = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)).split("/")[-1]

def create_app(app_name=PKG_NAME, **kwargs):
    app = Flask(app_name)
    if kwargs.get("celery"):
        init_celery(kwargs.get("celery"), app)
    from liveapp.all import bp

    app.register_blueprint(bp)
    return app
```

all.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, make_response,jsonify,request
import os
from .task import process_data

bp = Blueprint("all", __name__)
@bp.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello!"

@bp.route("/api/live", methods=["POST"])
def live():
    if request.is_json:
        data = request.get_json()
    process_data.delay(data)

    return  make_response(jsonify({"message":"JSON received"}), 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like celery is only starting a single worker in prefork mode. Messages wait in broker until the worker process is done with the execution of current tasks and won't consume new tasks.

By default, the worker concurrency defaults to number of cpu cores. You can specify the worker concurrency using `--concurrency` CLI. You can read about worker concurrency from [here.](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#concurrency)